# Changes to Vue components do not trigger Jest to rerun

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

Here is a snippet of my `package.json` file:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "test:unit": "jest --no-cache",
    ...
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I started unit test in the [watch mode](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#watchall):

```
npm run test:unit -- --watchAll
```

When I make any change to my test file `ProgressBar.spec.js`, I can see that the test has been rerun.

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import ProgressBar from '../ProgressBar.vue'

describe('ProgressBar', () => {
  ...
}
```

The problem is, when I make changes to my Vue component `ProgressBar.vue`, Jest does not rerun my test as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The fix I figured out is to do with Jest's configuration. Here is the addition of [moduleFileExtensions](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string) to the Jest configuration in my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "vue"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I started unit test in the watch mode:

```
npm run test:unit -- --watchAll
```

Now whenever I make any change to my Vue components, Jest will rerun the unit tests as expected.

Hope it helps.